# Setting various values by SetEnvIfNoCase is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, setenvif

I'm trying to filter some bots by blocking them in ".htaccess" file like this:

```
#UniversalRules
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ bad_bot #leave this for blank user-agents
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*\@.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* bad_bot
```

But these rules also block good bots, so I added below

```
#Goodbots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* good_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bingbot.* good_bot #bing
```

And finally the blocking rule

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

But when I'm using GoogleBot useragent (Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html) I'm getting - 403 forbidden.

What's wrong ?

Comment: google sets both variables.

Comment: @SalmanA  - Can you explain more clearly ? I think that at first block env=bad_bot, at second env=good_bot. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*GoogleBot* sets both environment variables; setting a variable (`good_bot`) does not unset other variables (`bad_bot`). You can set one variable and unset it afterwards:

```
#UniversalRules
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$           bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*\@.*       bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.*      bad_bot
#Goodbots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.*  !bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bingbot.* !bad_bot
```

See [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html) reference for examples. `BrowserMatchNoCase` provides identical functionality with shorter syntax. And you can remove all `.*` in your regex.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this tomorrow. But I'm  also trying to set variable as  `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* visitor=bad_bot`and check it later as `Deny from visitor=bad_bot` - but this don't work too.

Comment: `Deny from env=bad_bot` should work. In Allow or Deny, only the presence (or absence) of env variable is checked, not the value of the variable.